# Figuring Out The Rolling Average Of Average Tenure

Tags: mean, marketing

Here’s my question and it’s going to be pretty long winded.

My company works in the online space and we sell subscriptions. We’ve been selling subscriptions since like 2011. My boss wants me to figure out what average monthly tenure is of our subscribers is going back to January of 2013. So on January 2013, it was X and February of 2013, it was Y… and so on.

What I did was pull a master list of every subscription that was ever purchased and then I determined if it were active on January 31, 2013. If it was active, I took the total days that have passed between 01/31/2013 and when it was purchased. So if a subscription was purchased on 12/1/2012, it would be 62 days. If it were still active at the end of February, it would be 90 days (62 + 28 days in February). Once it cancelled, it stopped calculating. So if hypothetically, that dude who purchased on 12/1/2012 was still active today, his total days would be however many days have passed between then and today.

So when all is said in done, I take by each month, the average of total days active, divided by 31 (to signify a month).

The problem is, when I try to calculate the average tenure of what it is right now, it gets way too high. It’ll be like 22 months which I know is wrong. The average months on January 2013 is around 5.

Can anyone figure what, if anything, I’m doing wrong? I feel like I should be accounting for the time that has elapsed since January of 2013.